# python ElementTree: how to add SubElement text in bold

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

How can I create a SubElement of a Python ElementTree to write XML for this:

**Hi** What's up?

ie. where some text is bold and some isn't, but they both render on the same line when you print it out?
I think this is what the XML should look like.

```
<p>
  <b>Hi</b>
  What's up?
</p>
```

I've tried several things, including the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

p_element = ET.SubElement(section, "p")
bold = ET.SubElement(p_element, "b")
bold.text = "Hi" 
not_bold = ET.SubElement(bold, "p")
not_bold.text = "What's up?"
```

That gives the following and it ends up all being bold:

```
<p>
  <b>
     Hi
     <p> 
       What's up?
     </p>
  </b>
</p>
```

And if I instead do it like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

p_element = ET.SubElement(section, "p")
bold = ET.SubElement(p_element, "b")
bold.text = "Hi" 
not_bold = ET.SubElement(p_element, "p")
not_bold.text = "What's up?"
```

It gets the correct words in bold, but "Hi" and "What's up?" will render on different lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do next:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


p_element = ET.Element("p")
b_element = ET.SubElement(p_element, 'b')
b_element.text = "Hi"
b_element.tail = "What's up?"
print(ET.dump(p_element)) # <p><b>Hi</b>What's up?</p>
```

but don't use this module if you need to parse untrusted or unauthenticated data due to [XML vulnerabilities](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.html#xml-vulnerabilities).

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly. In terms of the vulnerabilities, is that the same story for the lxml package too?

Comment: you can check this table https://pypi.org/project/defusedxml/#python-xml-libraries